# Issue with responsive navigation on mobile device

Tags: html, css, iphone

I've had many issues implementing a responsive navigation. Fix an issue and it creates another. T

he newest problem I have to deal with is I can click on the ul links when the responsive navigation is closed.

Have a look at `www.smij.com.au` on mobile device to see the issue.

Please comment if you have any other issues with the website. Appreciate all the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Your li elements have a CSS rules for opacity 0 and after you show the nav they change their opacity to 1. The elements are still there, but they are not visually visible so you can click on them.

Usually dropdown menu is hiding ul dropdown element entirely with JS or with some CSS. There is much working examples on codepen.